# Making clickable list of images

Tags: android, listview

I want make a clickable and scrollable list of images. When image is clicked it should appear appropriate string in TextView.

I have list of Object which have images id and string id in itself:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
private int imageId;
private int stringId;
//(...)
}

public ArrayList<MyClass> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

How it is best to do? I do not know too much to go about it.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a custom list view. The list view shall consist of a custom layout, in which every line consists of a button. Then, you can assign each imageId to the buttons. Then, it  can display the related text using the same index in the list.

Comment: I think there is no need for a button `OnItemClickedListener`should do the job

Comment: Thanks. I think that this topic, however, was unnecessary :P